# Book with an parasitic race like the flood

Tags: story-identification, novel, horror, soft-sci-fi

I was going through a list of science fiction horror stories and one was mentioned with a parasitic alien race similar to the Flood from Halo.  I can't find the list again and don't know the author or publisher.  I think the list mentioned that the humans are 'possessed' by the parasite, but that they remain conscious/aware throughout.  Setting wasn't really mentioned, but there was interstellar travel.

Not much to go on, but hopefully someone knows what I'm looking for.

Comment: Unless you can offer some more info, this is really too broad to answer usefully. You've already turned down one which matches the brief description which suggests there's extra info that you haven't shared.

Comment: All 15 Stargate novels match this description. As do at least 10 Star Trek novels.

Comment: I don't have any extra information, so I can't really reword it.  Do I just leave it or is there some way that I 'deactivate' the question?

Comment: Closed questions disappear on their own. In the meantime, why not have a hunt for the list or try to remember any other info.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is quite a common trope in SF and there will be lots of possibilities. The one that immediately springs to mind is [The Pupper Masters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Puppet_Masters) by Heinlein. However, although there is interplanetary travel in the novel there is no interstellar travel. Also I can't remember what, if anything, is said about the state of mind of the possessed.

Comment: AFAIR there is no travel (neither interstellar nor interplanetary) at all in this book. All events occur on Earth, and we don't even know where the aliens come from.

Comment: @hindmost: The parasites come from Titan, and a mission is launched to Titan to destroy them. While checking this I came across the scene where Sam Cavanaugh is interrogated while possessed by the parasite and he does remain conscious of himself, but in a somewhat dreamlike state.

Comment: You're right. It seems that I've read a short version)

Comment: It's not The Puppet Masters.  But it is true that there will be many possibilities, so thanks anyway.